# Group by in HQL and Hibernate Criteria queries (ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

I am new to new to hibernate and Java, so I apologize if these are ridiculously simply questions.

I don't understand why the following query gives me the error "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression".

```
    Query q = session.createQuery (
                "select new tdata.Summary(tbForm.rYear, SUM(tbForm.pWaste)) " 
              + "from TrForm tbForm "
              + "left join fetch tbForm.indKey "        
              + "where tbForm.indKey.grpCode='999' " 
              + "group by tbForm.rYear "  );
```

The possible reasons for this error do not seem to apply to my query because I am including group by function SUM, and I do not have any expressions in the select that are not in the group by.

I also tried to write a criteria query to do what I need, and I could not get that to work either. In the criteria version, I am confused as to how to add restrictions to fetched data and how to get the data into the Summary object.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(TrForm.class)
                          .setFetchMode("DimInd",FetchMode.JOIN) 
                          .add(Restrictions.eq("indKey.indCode", "999")) 
                          .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                                    .add(Projections.groupProperty("rYear"))
                                    .add(Projections.sum("pWaste")));
summaryList = (List<Summary>) criteria.list();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

---

Update: 
Thank you so much! I removed the "left join fetch tbForm.indKey" and the HQL version worked!

Generalized query is

```
select R_YEAR, sum(P_WASTE) 
from TR_FORM tbForm 
left join DIM_IND ind 
on tbForm.IND_KEY = ind.IND_KEY 
where ind.GRP_CODE='999' 
group by tbForm.R_YEAR
```

tdata is the folder in which I have the java code for the data models.

Comment: What's the generated SQL query? Try to remove the `left join fetch tbForm.indKey` from the query: it's useless.

Comment: What is tdata in the HQL query?

Comment: Thank you so much! I removed the "left join fetch tbForm.indKey" and the HQL version worked!  

Generalized query is 
select R_YEAR, sum(P_WASTE) 
from TR_FORM tbForm 
left join DIM_IND ind 
on tbForm.IND_KEY = ind.IND_KEY 
where ind.GRP_CODE='999' 
group by tbForm.R_YEAR

tdata is the folder in which I have the java code for the data models.